# update column values based on groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have multi-index df, where one date index can have multiple records. How can I update `col_2` for each `bond_name`'s max `col_1`? What I have:

```
date        bond_name    col_1   col_2
2020-11-15  aaa          0.5     t1
            bbb          0.5     t1
2020-11-16  ccc          0.75    t1
2020-11-20  bbb          0.9     t1
            ddd          0.9     t1
2020-11-29  ddd          0.95    t1
```

And desired output:

```
date        bond_name    col_1   col_2
2020-11-15  aaa          0.5     t2
            bbb          0.5     t1
2020-11-16  ccc          0.75    t2
2020-11-20  bbb          0.9     t2
            ddd          0.9     t1
2020-11-29  ddd          0.95    t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('date')['col_1'].idxmax(),'col_2'] = 't2'
df
Out[83]: 
                      col_1 col_2
date       bond_name             
2020-11-15 aaa         0.50    t2
           bbb         0.50    t1
2020-11-16 ccc         0.75    t2
2020-11-20 bbb         0.90    t2
           ddd         0.90    t1
2020-11-29 ddd         0.95    t2
```

Comment: `df.groupby(level='bond_name')['col_1'].idxmax()` gives a `ValueError`